# Transfer a fresh image of Collections in MarkLogic database to a New server

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7

We need a fresh image of a couple of Collections of data present in one Marklogic database server to another server.

We tried to transfer the data using xqsync and MLCP, but it takes too long and the performance of the server goes down. If there is a quick way to do it, you my describe it here so we can manage it internally next time.

Could someone please provide information on ways to perform data transfer between MarkLogic databases which are in different servers.

Comment: What specifically did you try? How much data? How long did it take? What was the bottleneck? What are the topologies of the source and the destination clusters? You’re going to need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have backups and are working off of the same setup, a back up and restore could be the fastest for the full movement of the database.

Comment: Should both the servers be running the same MarkLogic version in order to restore from the backup.

Comment: Yes they should be the same version. It might work with other version but they should be the same version.

Comment: Thank you Hansen. I tried Backup and Restore and the data is copied though the servers have two different Marklogic version.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of options available to transfer data from one MarkLogic cluster to another MarkLogic cluster.

1. [Database replication](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication.pdf) : For this same number of forests need to be created in both cluster and databases need to configured for database replication.
2. [Flexible replication](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/flexrep.pdf) : This is asynchronous. It uses CPF as the underlying replication mechanism. The documents to be replicated are defined by a CPF domain. The scope of a domain may be a document, a collection of documents, or a directory.

Comment: My problem here is one of my server is running ML 7.0-5.4 and the other one ML 8.0-4.

Comment: With database replication they have to be the same but with flex rep they can be different.